# How to pass the user name in Scheduled script to PDF template using SS 2.0?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have made a scheduled script which is sending PDF though `email.send()`
I have get the filters as params from Suitelet. I want to get the name of the user (from runtime.getCurrentUser) and pass it to my PDF. I m just confused how to pass them and will that API be used in Suitelet or Sched script.
Can anyone help me with the code?

Here is my Scheduled script code:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType scheduledscript
 */
define(['N/ui/serverWidget', 'N/search', 'N/render', 'N/runtime', 'N/file', 'N/email'],
  function (ui, search, render, runtime, file, email) {

    function execute() {
      try {
        generateReport();
      }
      catch (e) {
        log.error('generateReport ERROR', e);
      }
    }

    function generateReport() {

      var slfilters = runtime.getCurrentScript().getParameter({ name: 'custscript_searchfilter_report' });
      log.debug('slfilters', slfilters);

      if (!!slfilters) {
        slfilters = JSON.parse(slfilters);
      }
      log.debug('slfilters2', slfilters);

      var user = runtime.getCurrentUser();//Need this user to be passed to my xml template

      var gender = slfilters.gender;//getting this from Suitelet
      log.debug('gender', gender);
      var item = slfilters.item;//getting this from Suitelet
      log.debug('item', item);

      var item_ = getItems(item, gender);
      log.debug('getItems(item, gender)', item_);
      //return item;

      var xmlTemplateFile = file.load(3918);
      //var template = script.getParameter({ name: 'custscript_template' });
      var renderer = render.create();
      renderer.templateContent = xmlTemplateFile.getContents();
      var customSources = {
        alias: 'searchdata',
        format: render.DataSource.JSON,
        data: JSON.stringify({
          value: item_,
        })
      };
      renderer.addCustomDataSource(customSources);

      var xml = renderer.renderAsString();
      var pdf = render.xmlToPdf({
        "xmlString": xml
      });

      email.send({
        author: 317,
        recipients: 'aniswtf@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Item Report',
        body: 'Report Generated: ',
        attachments: [pdf]
      });
    }

    //
    // ─── GET RESULTS ───────────────────────────────────────────────────
    //
    const getResults = function (set) {
      var results = [];
      var i = 0;
      while (true) {
        var result = set.getRange({
          "start": i,
          "end": i + 1000
        });
        if (!result) break;
        results = results.concat(result);
        if (result.length < 1000) break;
        i += 1000;
      }
      return results;
    };

    //
    // ─── GET ITEMS ───────────────────────────────────────────────────
    //
    function getItems(item, gender,user) {

      try {
        log.error('getItems Function started');
        var itemSearch = search.load({
          id: 'customsearch_mx_itemsearch'

        });
        var defaultFilters = itemSearch.filters;

        itemSearch.filters.push(
          search.createFilter({
            name: "custitem5",
            operator: 'anyof',
            values: gender
          }),
          search.createFilter({
            name: "internalid",
            operator: 'anyof',
            values: item
          })
        );

        //defaultFilters = arrFilters;
        //defaultFilters = defaultFilters.concat(arrFilters);
        //log.error('Updated Filters', defaultFilters)

        log.error('itemSearch', itemSearch);

        //return defaultFilters;
        var results = itemSearch.run().getRange({
          start: 0,
          end: 150
        });

        var result2 = results.map(function (x) {
          // var results = getResults(itemSearch.run()).map(function (x) {
          return {

            'category': x.getText({
              name: "custitem10",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'season': x.getValue({
              name: "custitem11",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'riselabel': x.getText({
              name: "custitem_itemriselabel",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'fit': x.getText({
              name: "custitem9",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'name': x.getText({ //sku
              name: "itemid",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'style': x.getText({
              name: "custitem8",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'inseam': x.getText({
              name: "custitem7",
              join: "parent"
            }),
            'wash': x.getText({
              name: "custitem_washname",
              join: "parent"
            }),
          };
        });

        log.debug('Results', results.length);
        log.debug('results', results);
        log.debug('result2', result2);

       // return results;//nabeeel's
        return result2;//mine

      } catch (e) {
        log.error('error in getItems', e)
      }

    }
    return {
      execute: execute
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no User in a Scheduled Script, so `runtime.getCurrentUser()` there will not return a value. You will need to retrieve the User via that method in the Suitelet (assuming it is not an anonymous external Suitelet).

From there you can add a Script Parameter to the Scheduled Script to hold the User, and then your Scheduled Script can read the Parameter and add the value as another Data Source on your template.

Comment: yes ur right! Thank You so much @erictgrubaugh this comment was so helpful to have an idea.